# how to put list's value using shell script in html

Tags: python, html, shell

Scenario: i got list variable from python which contains set of values and i want to put these list value in html file which is being generated runtime.

**testmail.sh**

**cat << *EOF* > ~/**test.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>

    My System information

    </title>

</head>

<body>

<h1> My system information : </h1>
```

for value in "$@" // this contains list value received from python.

do

## $value

done

```
</body>

</html>
```

*EOF*

above code is in testmail.sh which generates test.html which display values..

but i want this values to be put in body in html with proper format.. but it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are really piping to the bash script and not using "$@" arguments, because that doesn't make sense. =)

Example output:

```
$ echo -e "one\n two\n three" | bash foo.html 
<html>
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three</p>
</html>
```

Shell script that does it:

```
$ cat foo.html 
cat <<END
<html>
END
while read LINE
do
echo "<p>${LINE}</p>"
done
cat <<END
</html>
END
```

Comment: it's not working...
above solution is not clear to me.. i have to simply print list variables value in html file which is being generated from shell script .that variable is coming from another scripts..

Comment: how is it not working? Have you created that foo.html file? And tried to pipe your python's results to it?

Comment: i am telling complete scenario....

one python script say bc4jCheck.py which have below code

subprocess.call(["/bin/bash","/home/vikggupt/testmail.sh"] + correctList)
# where in correctList is list variable..

now in testmail.sh, i need two things
1. i want to generate html file and i want to iterate this list variable and put the value in the html file 
2. i want to send this html file into particular server... for this sending html fiie, i have already code... but for the 1st question, i need help...

Comment: Instead of the while loop, try `for i in $@; do echo "<p>$i</p>"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
python script.py |
sed -e '1i\<ul>' -e 's%.*%<li>&</li>%' -e '$a\</ul>'
```

... but it might be better still to add an option to the Python script to produce HTML(ish) output.

If you want to drive the shell script from Python, you might as well do the HTML formatting in Python, too.

```
import subprocess

pipe = subprocess.Popen("testmail.sh", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.stdin.write('<ul>\n')
for item in correctList:
    pipe.stdin.write('<li>%s</li>\n' % item)
pipe.stdin.write('</ul>\n')
pipe.stdin.close()
```

This assumes your `testmail.sh` reads its data from standard input, which apparently is not yet the case, so you'll need to change what you have slightly.

Comment: actually i have some code in shell script which is used for sending mails.. that's why i want to generate html file in shell script

Comment: i am telling complete scenario.... one python script say bc4jCheck.py which have below code subprocess.call(["/bin/bash","/home/vikggupt/testmail.sh"] + correctList) # where in correctList is list variable.. now in testmail.sh, i need two things 1. i want to generate html file and i want to iterate this list variable and put the value in the html file 2. i want to send this html file into particular server... for this sending html fiie, i have already code... but for the 1st question, i need help...

Comment: I'm afraid your comments don't make much sense. If you have a new question, post a new question.